# prevent angular update from overriding updated form data

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource, autosave

When performing an update using ngResource, any changes the user makes to the form between when the update is sent and received is lost when the update returns.

What can I do to ensure that any changes to the form remain when the update returns?

Here is an example to better explain the issue.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngResource'])
.factory('cartService', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/cart/items/:id ', { id: '@id' },{'update': { method:'PUT' }});
});

app.controller('cart', function($scope, $timeout, cartService, availabilityService) {
  //Initial Data
  $scope.item = cartService.get({'id':'1'}, function(){
  $scope.item.note = "Test";
  //save on a slow server
  $scope.item.$update;
  //Customer changes value before server response is received
  $scope.item.note = "For Customer X"
  //when server response is received the note is changed to "Test"
  });
```